# Run a process before compiling in Visual Studio C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

More exacly I want to run flex.exe "file.l" before compile to be able to compile lex.yy.c  after. If there is anyway to do this? I mean do it automatically in a way I only click run and do all?

Comment: Right-click properties and look at the Build tab - you can add pre-build (and post-build) steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Custom build steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e85wte0k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
Check Project Properties->Build Events

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is probably to add a custom build rule for .I files, so file2.I gets compiled as well. Additionally, pre-build steps run for every build, but custom build rules only run if the input file(s) changed.